# Alexa Skill AMAZON.Color matches on most inputs

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

Like most, I would expect that an utterance with a slot of type AMAZON.Color

e.g. "Is it {Color}" would only match on "red", "blue", "lavender" and the like.

Currently It's matching on standard colors as well as "is it bread", "is it killer monkey", "is it neil armstring" amongst others.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Do we have to make our own comprehensive list of colors until amazon fixes this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I have experienced this.

> When you create a custom slot type, a key concept to understand is
>   that this is training data for Alexa’s NLP (natural language
>   processing). The values you provide are NOT a strict enum or array
>   that limit what the user can say. This has two implications
>
> 1) words and phrases not in your slot values will be passed to you,
>
> 2) your code needs to perform any validation you require if what’s
>   said is unknown.

What mentioned above is for a custom slot and I guess this is applicable to Amazon predefined slots too.

You can validate the slot values in your backend code and respond with something like this

> Sorry, I didn't the get color you specified, can you try another one.